# Openweather API, Want the time to change based on city searched

Tags: reactjs, api, datetime, time, openweathermap

I'm using the openweatherapi to create a weather app in reactjs for fun. So far i've had no problems getting the current time to display but how would i go about getting it to change bases on the the city searched?? Any tips are greatly appricated!!

```
function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setWeather(result);
          setQuery('');
          console.log(result);
        });
    }
  }

  const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = d.getFullYear();

    return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
  }

  
   const time = (date) => {
     let hours = date.getHours();
     let minutes = date.getMinutes();

     return `${hours} : ${minutes} `
   }

  

  return (
    <div className={(typeof weather.weather != "undefined") ? 
        ((weather.weather[0].main === "Clear") ? 'app warm' :
         (weather.weather[0].main === "Thunderstorm") ? 'app thunderstorm' :  
         (weather.weather[0].main === "Snow") ? 'app snow' :
         (weather.weather[0].main === "Clouds") ? 'app clouds' :
         (weather.weather[0].main === "Rain") ? 'app rain' :
         (weather.weather[0].main === "Drizzle") ? 'app drizzle' : 'app') : 'app'}>
      <main>
        <div className="search-box">
          <input 
            type="text"
            className="search-bar"
            placeholder="Search City..."
            onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            value={query}
            onKeyPress={search}
          />
        </div>
        {(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? (
        <div>
          <div className="location-box">
            <div className="location">{weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}</div>
            <div className="date">{dateBuilder(new Date())}</div>
          </div>
          <div className="weather-box">
            <div className="temp">
              {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}°c
            </div>
            <div className="weather">{weather.weather[0].main}</div>
            <div className="time">{time(new Date())}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        ) : ('')}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've look through many question and answers but none seem to really work for me, or maybe i'm just not understanding the solutions that i've seen

Answer (score 0):

I've checked in your code and all seems to be fine. I bet the issue is coming from the api url. Probably you are missing `http://` or `https://` at the beginning.

The url for openweather should be something like:
`https://${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&appid=${api.key}`